# Identify this 2 axis motorized tripod

Tags: telescope, star-gazing

I am NOT an astronomy person, so this may be a dumb question, however I have recently found a tripod that appears to be for star tracking as far as I can guess. I would like to know the type of tripod and if possible the brand as it is not labeled and I do not know how to operate it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to be an alt-az type - that is, it can go left-right and up-down, but doesn't align directly with the Polar axis for star tracking.  It may well be a video camera tripod - the red "switch" looks, to me, like a brake/lock to hold the vertical position.  (It could probably be used for amateur astronomy if that's what you want to do.)

Comment: Well My hope was to adapt a DSLR tripod mounting shoe so that I can do very long photo exposures without trailing stars

Comment: Then you'll need an equatorial mount with a tracking motor. [Some suggestions](https://www.reddit.com/r/astrophotography/wiki/what_telescope#wiki_.241050_-_dsos). An alt-az mount will limit exposures to 20-40 seconds due to field rotation, even if you add a motor for tracking; see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQB6UnrTEEM) for an  explanation. If you're using a short focal length lens, not a telescope or supertele, options include [barndoor or automated trackers](http://www.budgetastro.net/tracking-the-stars.html).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It appears to be an older version of the [Bushnell Voyager Sky Tour 800x70mm Refractor Telescope](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/765323-REG/Bushnell_789971_Voyager_Sky_Tour_800x70.html)

Full manual [here](http://bushnell.com/getmedia/42f4f060-ea31-4b94-a77e-0bbddde87f95/voyager-skytour-2011.pdf?ext=.pdf)